# Only one intent or multiple intents on API.AI

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, amazon-lex

I use api.ai to create a chat bot which able you to order a list of services like "delivery", "home chef", "wash your clothes", ...

Should I create only one intent which gonna catch the type of service OR should I create one intent per service ? (Inside each service I need to catch the price, the date and location.)

I will use this agent through a basic chat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that each dialogue conversation will be identical for each of your services, there is no harm in creating a single `Intent` to handle all conversations.

The advantages of multiple `Intents` is extensibility, meaning it will be easier to make changes to a single service if you want to in the future.